# JavaScript Email validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-validate, email-validation

I want to apply javascript email validation in my project so please some suggest me the exact code for that because i just want to apply it only for regular expression and i don't want to add any plug in for it. is it possible to write some code in source file and apply to email field.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a regular expression validator to validate you email.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valRegExEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress"
                            Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please give a valid email address" ValidationGroup="StaffAddValidation" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z\.][a-zA-Z]{1,3}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

or if you want to check email from from javascript . check the SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks mahesh i checked that link and i got what i really required. Thank You once again

Comment: This will fail to validate domains that end .info and any others that are more than 3 chars long. It also doesn't allow for all the valid chars that can appear in an address.

Comment: @ChrisJ: i have just given a sample regular expression, we can customize the regular expression according to our needs. To work with domains of length more than 4 you can change this area {1,3} according to our need.

Comment: I'm pointing out the flaws with using a reg-exp. It's much better to just accept accept something of the form [string]@[string], and not even attempt to validate either of the strings. You can get into a world of pain very quickly. There's a good article at http://isemail.info/about which outlines the pitfalls.

Answer (score 3):

```
function validate(form_id,email) {

   var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
   var address = document.forms[form_id].elements[email].value;
   if(!reg.test(address)) {     
      alert('Invalid Email Address');
      return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression (/^([\w.-]+)@([\w-]+)((.(\w){2,3})+)$/i) to validate email address.
var emailRegex = new RegExp(/^([\w.-]+)@([\w-]+)((.(\w){2,3})+)$/i);

```
var valid = emailRegex.test(emailAddress);
if (!valid) {
alert("Invalid e-mail address");
return false;
} 
else
 return true;
```

Get example code here: http://www.codegateway.com/2012/03/regex-for-email-validation-javascript.html
 Also see example how to validate email address using RegularExpressionValidator
http://www.codegateway.com/2012/03/validate-email-format.html